# How to mock an ES6 class that extends another class using jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs, es6-class

I'm trying to mock a custom es6 class that extends another custom class and my unit test is throwing an error when attempting to test one of those class methods. I've tried changing the setup to work around the class mock altogether with no luck either. I would prefer to implement these tests the "right" way so I would appreciate some help getting this configuration working.

I've tried following the steps in the jest docs https://jestjs.io/docs/en/23.x/es6-class-mocks but after running jest.mock("path/to/class") it errors when I try to call Class.mockClear()

```
// GenericWorker.js

export default class GenericWorker {
    constructor(opt) {
        ...initialize worker with opt
    }

    subscribe() {
        ...do stuff
    }
}
```

```
// SpecializedWorker.js

export default class SpecializedWorker extends GenericWorker {

    onSubscribe() {
        this.subscribe();
    }
}
```

```
// __tests__/SpecializedWorker.spec.js

import SpecializedWorker from ('../SpecializedWorker');
jest.mock('../SpecializedWorker');

describ('SpecializedWorker', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    SpecializedWorker.mockClear();
  });

  it('should call onCallback', () => {
    ...testing stuff
  });
});
```

My test doesn't get past the beforeEach() step and claims that there is no method "mockClear()" on SpecializedWorker

I'm using node v.6.11 and jest v.23.6.0

Comment: A couple things. You have "describe" mispelled as "describ", not sure if that is a copy and paste from your actual test code or a transcribing error. Also, it looks to me like you're using the imported version of `SpecializedWorker` rather than the mocked one. Can you place the mock call before the import or is that a syntax error? In the Jest docs it shows the mock call happening before the `require`.

Comment: The typo is just a transcribing error. I'll try swapping the mock and import lines. Thanks @papiro

Comment: Did you manage to fix that issue?

Comment: In addition to what was said above, mocking the class under test is a bad practice

Comment: It appears the way I'm mocking it breaks the expected prototype chain. When I run `console.log(myInstance.constructor);` I get `[class MyClass extends mockConstructor]` where I expected `[class MyClass extends SuperClass]`.